# Get field attributes for an event

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to check if events have the `[NonSerlializedAttribute]`

```
using System;

[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    [field:NonSerialized]
    public event EventHandler SomeEvent;
}
```

But I'm stuck.

The [IEventSymbol](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/IEventSymbol.cs) does not offer an obvious way to get the [AssociatedField](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Symbols/Source/SourceFieldLikeEventSymbol.cs,99)

And the method [GetFieldAttributes](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/Symbols/EventSymbol.cs,102) is public but not included in the [IEventSymbol](http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/IEventSymbol.cs) interface.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: First of all, what is `IEventSymbol `?

Comment: @AgentFire did you notice the `[tag:roslyn]`?

Comment: Okay then. So, is it way kooler than the classic reflection?

Comment: Different use case but I'd say roslyn is kooler than reflection :)
I could use reflection to get what I want here but asking instead.

Comment: `(myIEventSymbol as EventSymbol).GetFieldAttributes()`? `IEventSymbol` is the super generic applies-to-all-languages-everywhere interface, it's not that unusual that some of the specifics get pushed down to an ABC.

Comment: @JeroenMostert `EventSymbol` is internal, potential API glitch here.